# Priority REST: No "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header in response

Tags: priority-web-sdk

No "*Access-Control-Allow-Origin*" header in response.
It prohibits any requests from the client.
Issue can be "solved" by rise proxy server, but it is not correct solution.

Is this issue are common for whole Priority REST ?
Can REST server return "*Access-Control-Allow-Origin: **" ?
Or how we can specify allowed domain list ?

Comment: Is your server self hosted or hosted by PrioritySoftware?

Comment: @naomi, yes it hosted by PrioritySoftware

Answer (score 0):

The definition comes from the server where the system is stored.
If you have access to the server, you can try to set it up there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are hosted on Priority-Software servers then I suggest you contact them
and ask them to add your domain to the Access-Control-Allow-Origin list.

Comment: good idea. We already addressed to them. And this is initiative of Priority Team to discuss all technical issues via stackoverflow...

Comment: Can you write the URL of the REST service? I can ask the IT team to add this header for this service.

Comment: I do not think that "stackoverflow.com" is a place where we should publish such information. Which channel should we use to discuss with Priority and share private information?

Comment: You can open a service call at the [Priority-Software](https://www.priority-software.com/) web site.